# jquery load function page call once time

Tags: jquery, load

```
var abc = (ajaxFunction.ajaxdata - 2);
for (i=0; i<abc; i++){
  $(".myDiv").load("myPage.php");
}
```

**This is my code block.**

`abc` variable is my ajax value. It's working. `alert(abc) --> 3,4,5` etc.

For loop work `"i < abc"` times but load function mypage.php call once time.

Thank you for your help, and sorry for my bad english :)

Comment: do you have google translate in your country?

Comment: Please add whole code of java script. Do you have use $( document ).ready(function(){..})?

Comment: .load() is the equivalent of .html() it emptys mydiv and then adds the ajax result

Comment: @user2960398 yes, i already use.

Comment: @madalinivascu  how can i call multiple time this page

Comment: @Piyon see my answer

Answer (score 0):

`.load()` is the equivalent of `.html()` it empties `.myDiv` and then adds the ajax result

Use a get ajax and `append` to add the page multiple times

```
$.get('myPage.php',function(data){
  $(".myDiv").append(data);
})
```